# How do I create a kick commands for a discord bot?

Tags: discord.js

i can't kick users with this code, can someone help me?

```
client.on('kick', message => {
  if(message.content === '/kick'){
    const target = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(target){
        const memberTarget = message.guild.members.cache.get(target.id);
        memberTarget.kick();
        message.channel.send("đã kick");
    }else{
        message.channel.send(`không thể kick`);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your event is wrong. You need to use [`client.on("message" ...`](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/#listening-for-messages) instead of `client.on("kick", ...`. Next you don't want to check if your [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) equals */kick* but only if it [`.startsWith("/kick")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith). Otherwise you won't be able to access the member you want to kick.

Additionally I suggest using `message.mentions.members` instead of `message.mentions.users` because it includes non-users (e. g. other bots) as well.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("/kick")) {
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (member) {
      member.kick();
      message.channel.send("đã kick");
    } else {
      message.channel.send(`không thể kick`);
    }
  }
});
```

Also don't forget to make sure your bot has the proper permission to kick somebody.

Answer (score 0):

"kick" is not the event you want. "message" is what you use instead

```js
client.on("message", message => {
//...
})
```

Comment: can you help me with this command? i still not working...